# What is the intuition behind this triangle inequality "trick"?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Sometimes in proofs related to limits I see the use of something like this: $$|a-b| = \mathbf{|(a-c)+(c-b)|} \leq |a-c|+|c-b|.$$

What is the logic of doing such thing apart from the reason that it just works?

Edit: An example:
[image]

Comment: Adding 0 in a clever way is one of the most important tricks in all of mathematics!  (Including the other favorite: multiplying by 1)

Comment: You might not know enough about $a$ and $b$ relative to each other but you may have information about each of them relative to another point, say c.

Comment: That's not actually an example of what you are talking about.  $|f(x) -L|$ and $|g(x) - M|$ don't have a term in common that gets cancelled out.

Answer (score 4):

*What is the intuition behind this triangle inequality “trick”?*

For the context of limits, I would say

> To ensure that the base of a triangle is small, it is enough to ensure that the other two sides are small.

[image]

For example, in the said context, we usually want to show that $|f(x)-L|$ is small (less than $\varepsilon$), provided that a certain condition is satisfied (usually, provided that $x$ runs over a small interval). The way we can do this is by showing that the "sides" $|f(x)-c|$ and $|c-L|$ are small (both at most $\varepsilon/2$), for some suitable $c$ (which usually depends on $x$ and whose relation with $f(x)$ and $L$ is known).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you'd like to bound the distance between $a$ and $b$, but you know that they're both less than a certain distance away from some $c$.
So, they can't be too far apart, since they're both 'close' to $c$.

Comment: Do you mean bound the distance between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Thanks for that, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a proof that the "straight" distance between $P$ and $Q$ will always be less or equal to any sum of distances between any intermediary points between $P$ and $Q$.

In proofs about limits presumably you might know stuff about $|a-c|$ and $|c-b|$ but not between $a$ and $b$.

Without context this is a pretty vague question.

Comment: I have added an example. Still don’t understand how it works logically on a graph.

Comment: Well, your example is perfect reason why we do it.  we are given Information about $|f(x) - L|$ and $|g(x) -M|$ and we want to know something about $|(f(x) + g(x)) - (L+M)|$.  Well, the most perfect tool we have in our belt is $|f(x) + g(x) - (L + M)|\le |f(x) - L| + |g(x)-M|$ ... which dumps the answer right in our lap!  Which makes the answer to your question: we do it because it allows us to find lims of sums by summing limits.

Comment: Yes but...I guess I just have to get used to it. sometimes it just unclear how someone would think about using this tool in such way without seeing it in other proofs before.